# I need to display an array of strings within ui-grid. Single row, one row for each ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I need to display each data from array in a single `ui-grid` row. Please help me, whether it's correct or not? so `data[0]` should display in one `ui-grid`  and `data[1]` should display in another `ui-grid`, so it looks multiple `ui-grid` in a single page.
but pls help me this scenario with for each condition, becz i dnt knw how much datas am having.

Controller.js:

```
             $rootScope.viewFollowup; // In this am having 'n' of datas only
             $scope.gridView={};

             $scope.data1= $.makeArray($rootScope.viewFollowup[0]);
             $scope.data2= $.makeArray($rootScope.viewFollowup[1]);
             $scope.data3= $.makeArray($rootScope.viewFollowup[2]);
           //$scope.gridOptions -- in this grid options am having all the columndefs                      details 

             $scope.aa=$scope.gridOptions;
             $scope.aa.data= $scope.data1;        

            $scope.ab= $scope.gridOptions;
            $scope.ab.data= $scope.data2;

            $scope.ac=$scope.gridOptions;
            $scope.ac.data=$scope.data3;    

            $scope.gridView=[$scope.aa,$scope.ab,$scope.ac];
            $rootScope.tabledata=$scope.gridView;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="group in tabledata track by $index">
    <div ui-grid="group" page-equalheight ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize class="grid" style=style="height:250px"></div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
Grid View 1
-------------------------------------------
a| b| c|d|
-------------------------------------------

Grid View 2
-------------------------------------------
c| d| e|f|
-------------------------------------------

    but what am getting is:
  Grid View 1
-------------------------------------------
c| d| e|f|
-------------------------------------------

Grid View 2
-------------------------------------------
c| d| e|f|
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You have to add `data` to gridOptions. Looks like you're attaching it to the scope. Also, What are you seeing with the code you have?

Comment: pls chk my code now,

Answer (score 0):

All `ui-grid` needs is a `gridOptions` object that contains data to show on the grid. You can put those `gridOptions` in an array and then loop over them in you markup using `ng-repeat`. Here is an example:

```
var gridOptions1 = {
data: [{
  "name": "Ethel Price",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Enersol"
}, {
  "name": "Claudine Neal",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Sealoud"
}, {
  "name": "Beryl Rice",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Velity"
}, {
  "name": "Wilder Gonzales",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "Geekko"
}]
};
var gridOptions2 = {
data: [{
  "name": "Georgina Schultz",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Suretech"
}, {
  "name": "Carroll Buchanan",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "Ecosys"
}, {
  "name": "Valarie Atkinson",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Hopeli"
}, {
  "name": "Schroeder Mathews",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "Polarium"
}, {
  "name": "Lynda Mendoza",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "Dogspa"
  }]

 };
```

$scope.grids = [gridOptions1, gridOptions2];

and then in your markup you can use `ng-repeat` like:

```
<div ng-repeat='options in grids'>
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="options" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9F3BkwX1gT72uVkaPWt?p=preview) is a working plnkr of the example above.